# Underscore equivalent of Lodash _.get and _.has

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I am trying to have search for Underscore equivalent for Lodash `_.get` and `_.has`, where it is able to directly access the existence and value of nested object value without the need of checking the existence of its parents.

However, it seems to me that underscore `_.get` and `_.has` only able to check the value for the first level.

```
var object = { 'a': { 'b': 2 } };
_.has(object, 'a.b'); // lodash shows true
_.has(object, 'a.b'); // underscore shows false
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, undercore doesn't perform a deep search, so you'll have to settle for shallow `has` and `get` (or change to lodash).

You can also try to implement it yourself (you can check lodash's implementation and try to copy it or come up with your own solution).

This is a simple solution to the `has` problem (`get` would be similar), using recursion and the current underscore `has`'s implementation.

Hope it helps.

```js
var a = {
  a: 1,
  b: {
    a: { c: { d: 1 }}
  }
};

var hasDeep = function(obj, path) {
  if(!path) return true;
  
  var paths = path.split('.'),
    nPath = _.first(paths);
  return _.has(obj, nPath) && hasDeep(obj[nPath], _.rest(paths).join('.'));
}

console.log(hasDeep(a, 'b.a.c.d'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are some external libraries that provide this:

- [underscore-contrib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/underscore-contrib)  [`getPath()`](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore-contrib/#getpath)
- [underscore-keypath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/underscore-keypath) `valueForKeyPath()`
- [underscore.get](https://www.npmjs.com/package/underscore.get) `get()`

Comment: "You must disclose your affiliation in your answers." https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion

Comment: There is also https://www.npmjs.com/package/underscore-keypath, which isn't as nicely named.

Answer (score 3):

You can add an extension to underscore with your custom method via `_.mixin`

this is the mixin that works like a `_.get` of `lodash` passing the chain of the object to evaluate i.e.

**Usage**

`_.get(a, 'a[0].b');`

`"collectionValue1" // you will get`

**Mixin**

```
_.mixin({
    get: function(obj, path) {
        if (!obj && !path) {
            return undefined;
        } else {
            var paths;

            if (!_.isEmpty(path.match(/^\[\d\]/))) {
                paths = path.replace(/^[\[\]]/g, '').split(/\./);
                nPath = _.first(paths[0].replace(/\]/, ''));
            } else {
                paths = path.split(/[\.\[]/);
                nPath = _.first(paths);
            }

            remainingPath = _.reduce(_.rest(paths), function(result, item) {
                if (!_.isEmpty(item)) {
                    if (item.match(/^\d\]/)) {
                        item = "[" + item;
                }
                    result.push(item);
                }

                return result;
            }, []).join('.');

            if (_.isEmpty(remainingPath)) {
                return obj[nPath];
            } else {
                return _.has(obj, nPath) && _.get(obj[nPath], remainingPath);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**Take a look to the sample**

```js
var a = {
a: [
  { b: "collectionValue1" },
  { b: "collectionValue2", list: [ { item: "listValue1" }, { item: [{value: "Working"}] }] }
  ],
  b: {
    a: {
      c: {
        d:"success"
      }
    }
  }
};

_.mixin({
  get: function(obj, path) {
      if (!obj && !path) {
          return undefined;
      } else {
          var paths;

          if (!_.isEmpty(path.match(/^\[\d\]/))) {
              paths = path.replace(/^[\[\]]/g, '').split(/\./);
              nPath = _.first(paths[0].replace(/\]/, ''));
          } else {
              paths = path.split(/[\.\[]/);
              nPath = _.first(paths);
          }

          remainingPath = _.reduce(_.rest(paths), function(result, item) {
              if (!_.isEmpty(item)) {
                  if (item.match(/^\d\]/)) {
                      item = "[" + item;
              }
                  result.push(item);
              }

              return result;
          }, []).join('.');

          if (_.isEmpty(remainingPath)) {
              return obj[nPath];
          } else {
              return _.has(obj, nPath) && _.get(obj[nPath], remainingPath);
          }
      }
    }
  });

  console.log(_.get(a, 'a[0].b'));
  console.log(_.get(a, 'b.a.c.d'));
  console.log(_.get(a, 'a[1].b'));
  console.log(_.get(a, 'a[1].list[0].item'));
  console.log(_.get(a, 'a[1].list[1].item[0].value'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This saved me a large amount of time (and frustration) in a project using underscore, coming from lodash. However, the logic does need to change to match the output from lodash: in particular, when a property is missing, `_.get` from lodash returns undefined -- this returns `false`

Altering to https://codepen.io/fluffynuts/pen/RJgjLo fixes this (I've also added lodash's `lowerCase` in there -- ignore it if you like)