# Replacent for _.get. (Lodash)

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

Lodash and Underscore Libraries seem to have a significant overlap.

We are using Underscore but there is legacy code that used _.get from Ladash.

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get

Is there a simple alternative (hopefully from Underscore) for that function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Underscore equivalent of Lodash \_.get and \_.has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42042245/underscore-equivalent-of-lodash-get-and-has)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deep path search is not supported in underscore: https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/issues/2370

You can try and use the `underscore.get` module.

Answer (score 0):

As of version 1.12 (November 2020), Underscore does have a `get` function similar to the one in Lodash, which does perform deep lookups (like many other functions already did). Moreover, if you really want to, you can override [`_.toPath`](https://underscorejs.org/#toPath) in order to support `'x.y.z'` notation instead of `['x', 'y', 'z']` in all functions that work with paths, including `_.get` and `_.has`. Do keep in mind that this can break existing code; if you need to lookup any properties that contain dots, you have to wrap such keys in singleton arrays.